# How to change/format just the time part of date in non-american format?

Tags: date, ms-access, format

I have a date/time field in my CSV file in **d/m/yyy h:nn:ss AM** format.

CSV is linked in MS Access and I want to convert the above field to **dd/m/yy hh:nn** format.

Sounds easy, but when I try `Format([Date Processed], "dd/m/yy hh:nn"` in my sql, it switches the **dd** and **m**. So **12/4/2015 (4-Dec-2015)** becomes **12/4/15 (12-April-2105)**

I do not want to play with my computer's date format as it may break my application. How can I do this within my SQL?

Comment: Can the down-voter please explain, what is wrong with this question?

Comment: It often just means that he/she didn't understand the question and then believes no one else will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Split in a simple function to shuffle the date parts:

```
Public Function ReFormat(ByVal Date1 As String) As String

    Dim DateParts   As Variant
    Dim DatePart    As String
    Dim TimePart    As String

    DatePart = Split(Date1, " ", 2)(0)
    TimePart = Split(Date1, " ", 2)(1)
    DateParts = Split(DatePart, "/")

    If UBound(DateParts) = 2 Then
        ReFormat = DateParts(1) & "/" & DateParts(0) & "/" & Format(DateParts(2) Mod 100, "00") & " " & TimePart
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `Format(CDbl([Date Processed]), "dd/m/yy hh:nn")`

Comment: This will fail - as the question itself demonstrates - in a non-US environment.

Comment: I'm using non-US environment and I use this for more than 2 years and its work with no problems , but I use CLng because I don't need time , so I hope this help Other, ( I Tried to add this as comment but I don't have 50 reputation to do that !!!.). thanks @Gustav

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up things. If `[Date Processed]` holds a Date, your expression will work, but the questioneer has a string expression for the date which will fail with `CDbl``or `CLng`. Thus, your comment doesn't really relate to the question. As a side note, `CLng` will round the date up if the time part is PM. To cut off time, use `Fix` like: `Format(Fix([Date Processed]), "dd/m/yy hh:nn")

Comment: So far @Gustav answer has been working nicely and hence I selected that as correct answer. However Fadi approach is much simplistic (if it works). I will test it when I get a chance and let you guys know.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav. maybe I miss understood the question, I assumed that the field [Date Processed] Data Type is Date/Time , and sure if it is String, using CDbl will not work, and you are right too that using CLng is unsafe if there is time part in the date and using Fix will be safer. thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Kashif: That's good!, but if the field [Date Processed] Data Type is Text so CDbl will not work.